# CEP Engine for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, complex-event-processing

Are there any CEP Engine/Platforms that works friendly with .Net (ie, it has .Net API), other than [Nesper](http://esper.codehaus.org/about/nesper/nesper.html) and the [Microsoft StreamInsight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee362541.aspx) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rulecore has a language independent interface, so does StreamBase. In Rulecore you send events using a high level protocol (like http, WS, TCP/IP sockets) and encode the events in XML. Streambase is similar. But these two products are standalone servers. If you are looking for something to embedd into your .net app you might find it hard to find a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

[Just have a look at Esper.net.](http://esper.codehaus.org/about/nesper/nesper.html)

It's open source and works pretty good for pattern detection.

Comment: Esper.net (or Nesper as it was called) is already mentioned in the question.

Comment: Even though NEsper is already listed, it may be that it's the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sybase CEP R4 (and R3) contains full SDK for .Net 3.5 for both publishing and subscribing to CEP data streams